# how to install pywin32 for latest pypy 3.5?

Tags: python, pywin32, pypy

after a google search still can't find easy way to install pywin32 to pypy (latest 3.5)- for cpython `pip install pywin32` works well, but not for pypy, an old version at link below seems not work either, any guide?
https://bitbucket.org/amauryfa/pywin32-pypy/downloads/

Comment: Have you tried building from source from [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)?

Comment: not yet... i can guess there will be many bugs as link above from amauryfa do many fix? and no any precompiled version?

Comment: I would bet that the opposite is true. The repository you hve linked was last updated 2012-09-17, while the official one was last updated 13 days ago. If there is a pre-compiled binary out there, it is not on PyPi

Answer (score 1):

You will need a compiler to `pip install pywin32` on PyPy, a binary wheel is not available. This [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) for CPython has some hints to get a compiler.